# How to diagnose an ERC20 error "Error: execution reverted" on a local testnet?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, erc20

I have a local testnet (represented by [this Docker image](https://github.com/mentiflectax/geth-poa-testnet)) and I am trying to send some ERC20 tokens from one address to another.

I use the following HardHat script for this:

```
npx hardhat run --network localTestnet scripts/send-usdt-to-exchange.js
```

which executes this file:

```
async function main() {
    const USDT = await ethers.getContractFactory("USDT");
    const usdt = await USDT.attach(
  "0xB816192c15160a2C1B4D032CDd7B1009583b21AF"
    );
    const amount = 1;
    const gas = 1000000;
    const exchange = "0x190FD61ED8fE0067f0f09EA992C1BF96209bab66";
    const usdtSender = "0xDd1e8cC92AF9748193459ADDF910E1b96E88154D";

    console.log("Approving the transfer...");
    await usdt.approve(usdtSender, amount + gas);
    console.log("Done");
    console.log("Sending USDT...");
    const result = await usdt.transferFrom(usdtSender, exchange, amount, { gasLimit: gas });
    console.log("Done, result=", result);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

A couple of minutes after I execute this script I can see in Blockscout that the transaction failed with `Error: execution reverted` error.

I see some output in Blockscout under `Raw Trace`.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

```
[
  {
    "action": {
      "callType": "call",
      "from": "0x411167fefecad12da17f9063143706c39528aa28",
      "gas": "0xEEC98",
      "input": "0x23b872dd000000000000000000000000dd1e8cc92af9748193459addf910e1b96e88154d000000000000000000000000190fd61ed8fe0067f0f09ea992c1bf96209bab660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
      "to": "0xb816192c15160a2c1b4d032cdd7b1009583b21af",
      "value": "0x0"
    },
    "error": "execution reverted",
    "subtraces": 0,
    "traceAddress": [],
    "type": "call"
  }
]
```

The USDT contract is deployed on the testnet using [this script](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i20/erc20/npm-prj/scripts/deploy.js):

```
async function main() {
  // We get the contract to deploy
    const USDT = await ethers.getContractFactory("USDT");
    const usdt = await USDT.deploy("0x190FD61ED8fE0067f0f09EA992C1BF96209bab66", "0xDd1e8cC92AF9748193459ADDF910E1b96E88154D");


  console.log("USDT contract deployed to:", usdt.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

The [contract](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i20/erc20/npm-prj/contracts/USDT.sol) itself looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./tokens/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract USDT is ERC20 {
    constructor(address exchange, address usdtSender) ERC20("Test Tether", "tUSDT") {
        _mint(exchange, 1000000000000000000000);
        _mint(usdtSender, 1000000000000000000000);
    }
}
```

Given that all of this happens on a local testnet, what can I do to diagnose `execution reverted` error and how to fix it?

**Update 1:** I noticed a strange behavior.

Before executing `send-usdt-to-exchange.js`, I add ETH to the `usdtSender` account (`0xDd1e8cC92AF9748193459ADDF910E1b96E88154D`) by opening the geth shell and running the following commands:

```
geth attach http://localhost:8178

web3.personal.unlockAccount('0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28',
'carsdrivefasterbecausetheyhavebrakes', 600);

eth.sendTransaction({
  from: '0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28',
  to: '0xDd1e8cC92AF9748193459ADDF910E1b96E88154D',
  value: web3.toWei(1000, 'ether')});
```

This returns the transaction ID `0x76794f48a21518a3b3acfe820c2a57f88c188949054573be1805894bb9627471` and in BlockScout this transaction is marked as successful:

[image: Screenshot of a successful transaction in BlockScout]

"Raw trace" in Blockscout looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "action": {
      "callType": "call",
      "from": "0x411167fefecad12da17f9063143706c39528aa28",
      "gas": "0x0",
      "input": "0x",
      "to": "0xdd1e8cc92af9748193459addf910e1b96e88154d",
      "value": "0x3635C9ADC5DEA00000"
    },
    "result": {
      "gasUsed": "0x0",
      "output": "0x"
    },
    "subtraces": 0,
    "traceAddress": [],
    "type": "call"
  }
]
```

However, if I call

```
console.log("Determining the ETH balance of USDT sender...");
const ethBalance = await usdt.provider.getBalance(usdtAddress);
console.log("ETH balance:", ethBalance);
console.log("Done");
```

in `send-usdt-to-exchange.js` (after the transaction is marked as successful in Blockscout) I get the output

```
Determining the ETH balance of USDT sender...
ETH balance: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true }
Done
```

For some reason, the ETH balance of the USDT sender is zero even though the transaction was successful.

**Update 2:** Inside the geth shell, `eth.getBalance("0xDd1e8cC92AF9748193459ADDF910E1b96E88154D");` (ETH balance of the USDT sender account) returns `2e+21`.

**Update 3:** Looks like "execution reverted" error is triggered in [instructions.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go) file in Go-Ethereum:

```
func opRevert(pc *uint64, interpreter *EVMInterpreter, scope *ScopeContext) ([]byte, error) {
    offset, size := scope.Stack.pop(), scope.Stack.pop()
    ret := scope.Memory.GetPtr(int64(offset.Uint64()), int64(size.Uint64()))

    interpreter.returnData = ret
    return ret, ErrExecutionReverted
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dirty hack that seems to work.

First, add a method to the contract which transfers funds without changing the allowance:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./tokens/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract USDT is ERC20 {
    constructor(address exchange, address usdtSender) ERC20("Test Tether", "tUSDT") {
        _mint(exchange, 1000000000000000000000);
        _mint(usdtSender, 1000000000000000000000);
    }

    function transferFromWithoutChangingAllowance(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, change the script:

```
async function main() {
    const USDT = await ethers.getContractFactory("USDT");
    const usdtAddress = "0xa682a5972D1A8175E2431B26586F486bBa161A11";
    const usdt = await USDT.attach(usdtAddress);
    const amount = 1;
    const exchange = "0x190FD61ED8fE0067f0f09EA992C1BF96209bab66";
    const usdtSender = "0xDd1e8cC92AF9748193459ADDF910E1b96E88154D";

    console.log("Determining the ETH balance of USDT sender...");
    const ethBalance = await usdt.provider.getBalance(usdtSender);
    console.log("ETH balance:", ethBalance);
    console.log("Done");
    
    console.log("Approving the transfer...");
    const approveResult = await usdt.approve(usdtSender, amount+1);
    console.log("Done, result: ", approveResult);
    console.log("Sending USDT...");
    const result = await usdt.transferFromWithoutChangingAllowance(usdtSender, exchange, amount, { gasLimit: 1000000 });
    console.log("Done, result=", result);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```